# Ubuntu 14.04 not going to sleep

Tags: 14.04, system

My ubuntu 14.04 won't go to sleep. I'm not sure if it happened after a system upgrade from 13 or something else.

I tried a few solution including creating scripts that disconnect usb ports, ssd hard drive... none of them worked.

What can I do to start identify the problem ?

**Edit**

I'm really sorry, I forgot to add the details I had in mind when preparing the question...
It happens when I click "suspend" in the system menu or close the lid. It goes to sleep but awakes immediately after with a message like "early wake event detected"

Thanks for your answers and comments, here is the resutl of `lspci -nn`

```
julien@venus:~$ lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port [8086:0151] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1e14] (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1e16] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e57] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] [10de:0de3] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0888] (rev c4)
0c:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
```

Comment: What you mean by "won't go to sleep"? It will wake up immediately right after you suspend it? Or the suspend button does not work for you? Please paste the output of `lspci -nn` command from your terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t), and update your question by [editing](http://askubuntu.com/posts/581108/edit) it.

Comment: No idea anyone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your system has a dedicated video card as per your `lspci` output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] [10de:0de3] (rev a1)
```

Sometimes these video cards need additional driver to make it work with suspend.

Please install the proprietary driver by searching "driver" in your dash:
[image]

And install the nvidia driver from it.

To be more specific, you could check your `dmesg` output after it failed to suspend, you might see some message like "failed suspend". And it might be able to tell you what device is causing this issue.

Comment: Looks like this is the one. I just needed to reboot too. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're experiencing a known bug with suspending. You can have a read of [this fairly easy to follow guide](http://thecodecentral.com/2011/01/18/fix-ubuntu-10-10-suspendhibernate-not-working-bug) which seems to have fixed this bug for most people.

Hope this has helped you.

Comment: Thank you for the script, but this is the 3rd or 4th I tried, and unfortunately not working... I guess those scripts are very particular to precise problems, I think I first need to identify my problem.